# Angular 2+: Stop form validation after required validator fails

Tags: validation, angular, typescript

Given a reactive angular form like this:

```
buildForm(): void {
    this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({
      'email': [this.user.email, [
        Validators.required,
        Validators.email
      ]],
    });
```

How can I get angular to stop the form validation after the required validator failed? I don't want that both messages "email is required" and "email is invalid" get displayed at the same time. 
My guess would be to write a custom validator. Is there a better / less verbose / already built-in way to do this?

I am using angular 4.0.2

Comment: Look at Validators.compose. May be you can write wrap it and filter out errors as you needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a better / less verbose / already built-in way to do this?

for now, Angular Form does not support yet. create custom validator is great solution.

future: yeap, it's coming, please watch this talk https://youtu.be/kM5QBOWrUVI?t=16m18s